# pillow: ошибка c кириллицей

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow

Сама ошибка

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\raingm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    return font.getsize(text, direction, features, language, stroke_width)
  File "C:\Users\raingm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 128, in getsize
    return self.font.getsize(text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Код

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
image = Image.new("RGBA", (1100, 500), (0, 0, 0, 0))

idraw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
name = 'фыафыа'
font_40 = ImageFont.truetype("Roboto-Regular.ttf", size = 40)

W, H = (1100, 500)
msg = f"{name}"
w, h = idraw.textsize(msg)
idraw.text(((W-w)/2, 315), msg, fill="cyan", font=font_40)
image.show()
```

Comment: Вы используете русский текст, поэтому попробуйте сделать `name = 'фыафыа'.encode('cp1251')`

Comment: Получаю "b'\xf4\xfb\xe0\xf4\xfb\xe0'", как я могу это декодировать уже в само слово('фыафыа')?

Comment: `name.decode()`

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался